# Segmentation Fault with Malloc

Tags: c, queue, malloc, abstract-data-type

I needed to implement and specific ADT, strqueue, for my CS class today and so I wrote up two functions: create_StrQueue(), and add_to_back(StrQueue sq, const char* str). Unfortunately, when I call create_StrQueue in add_to_back I get a seg fault, and  I am unable to figure out why exactly. Here is the code that I wrote for these two functions:

[edit] I should probably malloc tempWord in add_to_back.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

// A strqueue is an ADT consisting of words
struct strqueue{
  StrQueue back;    // last StQueue in queue
  StrQueue next;    // next StrQueue in queue

  char* word;       // stored string
  int length;       // length of entire queue
};

typedef struct strqueue* StrQueue;

StrQueue create_StrQueue(void){

  StrQueue retq = malloc(sizeof(struct strqueue));  // get memory for a new strqueue
  retq->word = malloc(sizeof(char*)); 
  retq->word = NULL;
  retq->back = retq;       // set back pointer to itself
  retq->next = NULL;       // nothing after this strqueue yet

  return retq;
}

void add_to_back(StrQueue sq, const char* str){

  char* tempWord;
  sq->length++;

  for(int i=0; str[i]; ++i) tempWord[i]=str[i];  // copy string for the new strqueue

  if(sq->word==NULL) sq->word = tempWord;  // input strqueue was empty

  // input StrQueue was not empty, so add a new StrQueue to the back
  StrQueue new = create_StrQueue(); // results in seg fault
  new->word = tempWord;
  sq-back->next = new;  // swaping pointers around to add malloced StrQueue to the back
  sq->back = next;
}
```

I'm at a loss, and so I'm hoping someone can clarify what exactly is going on, because when I run main like so;

```
int main(void){

char* str1 = "Hello";

StrQueue sq = create_StrQueue(); // does not cause seg fault
add_to_back(sq, str1);
}
```

calling create_StrQueue() for the first time works just fine.

Comment: 1)`tempWord[i]=str[i];` is wrong.

Comment: How-so? I ran a little piece of code to print out tempWord after that loop to see if it had copied the string, and it indeed did.

Comment: 1)Area for storing is not ensured.

Comment: tempWord isn't initialized to anything.  Writing to it is incorrect.

Comment: 2)`retq->word = malloc(sizeof(char*));retq->word = NULL;` memory leak. Meaningless `malloc`.

Comment: this line: for(int i=0; str[i]; ++i) tempWord[i]=str[i]; copies 'str' to where tempWord points.  However, tempWord is not pointing to anywhere in particular.  This is undefined behaviour and can/will result in a seg fault event.

Comment: BTW: this line: typedef struct strqueue* StrQueue; results in the fact of StrQueue being a pointer is hidden in the rest of the code.  Much Much better to remove that typedef statement and use 'struct strqueue * StrQueue; when ever a StrQueue variable/pointer is needed.  Even better yet if the StrQueue were named pStrQueue

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for the tip, and I agree about the typedef as well - but it was provided to us and we were told we must use it as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char*` in the struct is a pointer to a character array. `retq->word = malloc(sizeof(char*));`
is not the right way to allocate a string; what this actually does is it *assigns a tiny array* to `word`, essentially useless, and then you overwrite what you just allocated by assigning `NULL` to `word`, leaking the memory. All memory allocated by `malloc` must be manually released later on with `free`. You are dealing with a pointer. Assigning data to it has no magic involved in C, you are simply replacing the value of the pointer itself.

In `add_to_back`, you need to allocate space to tempWord before copying data into it:

`tempWord = malloc( strlen(str)+1 );`

You add 1 to accommodate the null terminator in the string. Use `strcpy` to copy into `tempWord` instead of writing your own string copying method there, your method does not add a null terminator.

An even better solution would be to have create_StrQueue accept a `const char*` parameter, and do the string allocation and copying in there.

You should also avoid using the word `new` since that looks a bit confusing to a c++ programmer. :)